# http 500 error in iis

Tags: php, http, iis

I have a php program to get values from database and update the values by using web service.It runs for 7 hrs and then in the logs I see 500 internal server error and nothing else to troubleshoot.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: A little bit more information would be nice, like your code, stack traces or anything to get a hold on...

Comment: You might want to try this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725786%28v=ws.10%29.aspx and this http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging